# is it possible to keep the vite watch when compile failed

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite

I am using this vite(`vite/2.7.13 darwin-arm64 node-v16.13.2`) command to watch the file changes and rebuild project:

```
vite build --watch
```

now I am facing a problem that when the compile failed, the watch process exits automatically. is it possible to keep the watch process and make it did not exits when compile failed?